# Making bigger matrices out of smaller matrices in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem making a bigger matrix out of smaller matrixs.

Lets suppose i have the matrices:

```
      1 2 3
  A=  4 5 6
      7 8 9
```

and

```
      1 0 0 
  B=  0 1 0
      0 0 1
```

The result i want to get is

```
    1 2 3 1 0 0
C = 4 5 6 0 1 0
    7 8 9 0 0 1
```

If I'm to do this in MATLab it would be as simple as doing C = [A B]

But I'm working with python at the momment.

How could one do that thing in python?

Btw, in python the matrices A and B would be made by my program and they would be ndarrays (at my problem, they are 15000x1626 arrays, or matrices, if needed to be).

Thanks alot for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using [`np.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
C = np.hstack((A,B))
```

or [`np.concanenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate):

```
C = np.concatenate((A,B),axis=1)
```

Comment: oh, np.hstack it is... concatenate make it looks strange.. thanks alot for the help.... accept and upvote..... I've tried np.hstack before posting here.. but i had something wrong at it :X)