# Merging matrices in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I have some matrices with different lengths. The sizes are 200*59 , 200*1 and 200*1 and I want to make a big matrix of 200*61. How should I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making bigger matrices out of smaller matrices in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791528/making-bigger-matrices-out-of-smaller-matrices-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concatenate` from `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(200,59)
b = np.random.rand(200,1)
c = np.random.rand(200,1)

d = np.concatenate((a,b,c),axis=1)
print d.shape #(200,61)
```